# Program should wait for pressed button (Java)

Tags: java, swing, button, wait

My specific problem is: In the code below the program runs and goes directly to the last line “system.out.println(“ go to this point”)”. I want that it waits until one pressed the button (buttonsav) choose some files.  Later these files are processed. The program cannot run without these files. So, how to let the program wait for buttonclick. After the clicks the program shoud go to the last line "system.out.... and proceed then not before!! Here is the code which I reduced to make the problem clearer:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
 import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


 import java.util.prefs.*;


 public class FileRead_3 extends JFrame 
 {
      Boolean filesAdded = false;
      String path ="";
      static  int status =0;
      public FileRead_3()
      {

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {      

        FileRead_3 eval = new FileRead_3(); 
        Preferences pref = Preferences.userRoot();
        eval.path = pref.get("DEFAULT_PATH", "");
           JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("BGMN-Auswertung-Optimierung");  
           frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
           frame1.setSize(1000, 800);                                
           frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
           JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
           BorderLayout bol = new BorderLayout();

           JButton buttonsav   = new JButton("open sav files");
           JButton buttonlst   = new JButton("open lst files");

           eval.filesAdded=false;

           System.out.println("filesaddedbefore "+eval.filesAdded);


               eval.filesAdded = true;
              buttonsav.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                  eval.filesAdded = true;
                   // Code to run after button is pressed.

                 System.out.println("Hello sav-world");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1,  " Choose sav-File!");

                JFileChooser chooser_sav = new JFileChooser();  // 1907  
                chooser_sav.setCurrentDirectory(new File(eval.path));
FileFilter sav_filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt-files",".txt");
                chooser_sav.addChoosableFileFilter(sav_filter);
                chooser_sav.setFileFilter(sav_filter);  // 20.07.2016

                chooser_sav.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);             
                status = chooser_sav.showOpenDialog(null); //18.11.2016

               } // action performed
           }); //action listener
            //  eval.filesAdded = true;


           panel1.add(buttonsav);               
           panel1.add(buttonlst);
           frame1.getContentPane().add(panel1);
           frame1.setVisible(true);
           System.out.println("go to this point");
      }
 }
```

---

There is still a problem: when I choose while(eval.filesAdded != false) then it goes directly to the last line "system.out... when I use while(eval.filesAdded == false)I get an endless loop
Here the code so what do I still wrong ?

```
 public class FileRead_3 extends JFrame 
 {
     Boolean fileAdded = false;
   public FileRead_3()
   {
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) 
   {      
    FileRead_3 eval = new FileRead_3(); 

           JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("BGMN-Auswertung-Optimierung");  
           frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
           frame1.setSize(1000, 800);                                
           frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
           JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
           BorderLayout bol = new BorderLayout();
           MigLayout mlayout = new MigLayout("align 20% 20%","[][] [40]", "[]40[]");
           panel1.setLayout(mlayout);

           JButton buttonsav   = new JButton("open sav files");
           JButton buttonlst   = new JButton("open lst files");
    eval.filesAdded=false;
           System.out.println("filesaddedbefore "+eval.filesAdded);
              while(eval.filesAdded != false)
           {             
              buttonsav.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                  eval.filesAdded = true;
                   // Code to run after button is pressed.

                   System.out.println("Hello sav-world");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1,  " Choose sav-File!");

             JFileChooser chooser_sav = new JFileChooser();  // 1907  
             chooser_sav.setCurrentDirectory(new File(eval.path));
 FileFilter sav_filter= new FileNameExtensionFilter("Sav-files", ".sav");
                chooser_sav.addChoosableFileFilter(sav_filter);
                chooser_sav.setFileFilter(sav_filter);  // 20.07.2016

                chooser_sav.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);          
                status = chooser_sav.showOpenDialog(null); //18.11.2016

               } // action performed
           }); //action listener
            //  eval.filesAdded = true;
           } // ende while



           panel1.add(buttonsav);
           panel1.add(labsav,"wrap");
           panel1.add(buttonlst);
           panel1.add(lablst,"wrap");
           frame1.getContentPane().add(panel1);
           frame1.setVisible(true);

           buttonsav.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
           {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
             {
                 System.out.println("Hello world");
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1,  " Choose sav-File!");

                  JFileChooser chooser_sav = new JFileChooser();  

                  chooser_sav.setCurrentDirectory(new File(eval.path));
 FileFilter sav_filter= new FileNameExtensionFilter("Sav-files", ".sav");
                  chooser_sav.addChoosableFileFilter(sav_filter);
                   chooser_sav.setFileFilter(sav_filter);                        
                  chooser_sav.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);                 
                  status = chooser_sav.showOpenDialog(null);                      
                  if(status != chooser_sav.APPROVE_OPTION)
                  {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No sav-file chosen!!");
                         System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                         eval.fsav = chooser_sav.getSelectedFiles(); 
                         chooser_sav.setCurrentDirectory(eval.fsav[0]);


                  }
             }
           });
  buttonlst.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
           {
                 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
                 {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1,  " Choose lst-File!");
         JFileChooser chooser_lst = new JFileChooser();
         chooser_lst.setCurrentDirectory(new File(eval.path));
  FileFilter lst_filter=new FileNameExtensionFilter("Lst-files", ".lst");
         chooser_lst.addChoosableFileFilter(lst_filter);
         chooser_lst.setFileFilter(lst_filter);
chooser_lst.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

                   int status2 = chooser_lst.showOpenDialog(null);       
                   if(status2 != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION || status != chooser_lst.APPROVE_OPTION)
                   {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1, "No lst-file chosen!!");

                          System.exit(0);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       eval.flst = chooser_lst.getSelectedFiles(); 
                       chooser_lst.setCurrentDirectory(eval.flst[0]);

                   }
                 }
           });  
      System.out.println("program runs to this point");
```

Comment: Consider the alternative of having a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame` (or, better, a dialog containing the frame), setting it as modal (`java.awt.Dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType)`) and in this way the call `setVisible(true)` will not return until the dialog is dismissed. AFAIK this is better practice than coding a waiting loop yourself.

Comment: Look up *event-driven programming*.  You create the GUI and exit the program.  When a JButton is pressed, your action listener code executes and then exits when finished.

Comment: Is it possible to handle this problem with threads ?